# sql server for credit and debit

Tags: asp.net

```
cust_ID   Credit   Debit   Amount

1          1000             1000
                     200     800
           2000             2800
            200             3000
```

Here I show you the model table. If I enter some amount in credit column it will display in amount column without affect of any column. If I enter some no in debit column it will deduct in amount column. I need sql query for this anybody have an idea please help me for that.

Comment: Please align your post properly and explain your problem properly.

Comment: Also, please explain what you have tried. Stack Overflow wasn't created for people to do all the work for you.

Comment: My column Acct_ID,DATE,CREDIT,DEBIT. When i using select statement.i need a proper transaction details with amount. that is my question please provide me proper solution.

Comment: i didn't try anything. if i use select statement i want to get the correct transaction please help me soon.

Comment: Actually my table is
ACC_ID     DATE DEBIt CREDIT
1   11/3/2014 0 1000
1   11/3/2014 500 0
1   11/3/2014 0 1000
1   11/3/2014 0 2000
1   11/3/2014 1000 0

But i need this output what i have to do.

ACC_ID DATE        DEBIt CREDIT AMOUNT
1 11/3/2014 0 1000 1000
1 11/3/2014 500 0 500
1 11/3/2014 0 1000 1500
1 11/3/2014 0 2000 3500
1 11/3/2014 1000 0 2500

Answer (score 0):

For updating the current values in SQL you use the following query.

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET Column_Name = Value [, Column_Name(s) = Value(s)];
```

When this is executed, the table is updated with the new value. If you want to update the Credit column, just write those column names, add a WHERE clause as per requirement.

Comment: Actually my table is
ACC_ID     DATE DEBIt CREDIT
1   11/3/2014 0 1000
1   11/3/2014 500 0
1   11/3/2014 0 1000
1   11/3/2014 0 2000
1   11/3/2014 1000 0

But i need this output what i have to do.

ACC_ID DATE        DEBIt CREDIT AMOUNT
1 11/3/2014 0 1000 1000
1 11/3/2014 500 0 500
1 11/3/2014 0 1000 1500
1 11/3/2014 0 2000 3500
1 11/3/2014 1000 0 2500

Answer (score 0):

Happie i got the answer.i wish to share this with you all who given me an idea.
         CREATE table mutations
( 
 Account INTEGER,
 Date DATETIME,
 Debit DECIMAL(9,2),
 Credit DECIMAL(9,2)
)

select * from mutations

INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (10139, '2007-08-31', 0.0, 2025.91)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (10139, '2007-08-31', 0.0, 3620.11)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (10139, '2007-09-30', 4631.52, 0.0)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (10139, '2007-09-30', 0.0, 11336.71)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (10139, '2007-09-30', 0.0, 14.8801)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (12211, '2007-08-31', 0.0, 1352.76)
INSERT INTO mutations VALUES (12211, '2007-08-31', 1000.0, 0)

SELECT
 account,
 date,
 SUM(Debit) AS Debit,
 - SUM(Credit) AS Credit,
 (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(m2.Credit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(m2.Debit),0) FROM mutations m2 WHERE m1.account = m2.account AND m2.date <= m1.date AND

CASE WHEN m2.Credit <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END <= CASE WHEN m1.Credit <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

) AS Balance
FROM
 mutations m1
GROUP BY
 account,
 date,
 CASE WHEN Credit <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY
 account,
 date,
 CASE WHEN Credit <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END